# Connect domain name to web host

Tags: web, web-hosting, nameservers, registrar

Maybe I'm not asking (Google) the right questions, but I can't seem to find the "full" answer on how to connect a domain name (which I just bought from namecheap.com) to my web host.

They all say something like "just get the name servers of your web host, add them to the registrar's DNS configuration page, and BAM!, your done.

However, I'm on a shared hosting plan.  So if I look up the name servers for:

```
subdomain.website.com
```

I find what look like three generic name servers.  But my website is located at:

```
subdomain.website.com/~username/
```

How will those generic name servers be able to identify that I want my website to point to my specific username?  Shouldn't there be some configuration on the side of the web host?  Do I need to add the connection to my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

First, set up the generic nameservers in Namecheap to point to your hosts nameservers that you have identified.

Then go into your hosting control panel at your hosting provider, which I assume will be at:
subdomain.website.com/~username/cpanel

If your host is using CPanel you will have an option to 'Add-On' a domain.

If your host is not using Cpanel, look through the other options on your hosting account or contact their support to find out where to 'add-on' the domain to your account.

Comment: cpanel didn't work so I'm afraid I will need to look into "adding" the domain.  Technically speaking, how is that done?  To httpd.config or .htaccess? some other way?

Comment: Apologiess for the delay Kevin, went on holiday: I trust you got this sorted out?

Comment: Unfortunately, my host doesn't provide the services that I need.  Instead, I'm having to frame the URL using namecheap's URL framing feature.  It works, but not the way I would like because sub-pages on my website don't show up in the URL.

Comment: If it doesn't allow you to link a domain to your webspace, it's not really a webhost! You can get hosting space dirt cheap - domainregistrationuk.com have a sale on right now, or just search for a big provider who offer GOOD support to get you started. Linking domain name to webspace is one of the most basic tasks that any webhost should hold your hand through. =)

Comment: I was getting FREE web hosting through my school.  Yes, FREE.  Which is why I was putting up with it. And yes... WAS.  It didn't have enough of what I needed so I decided to fork over a little bit of cash in order have a real web host.  It was definitely worth it...